# I want to add my java path but i don't understand , among all of these path, in which i should add my java path?

Tags: java, path

I want to add my java path but i don't understand , among all of these path, I which should add my java path?

[image: Image showing PATH variables]

Comment: It's not really clear what your problem is. You're editing a environment variable that contains a java path among other things. What are you actually trying to achieve? What's confusing you? For a better screenshot consider using the Windows Snipping Tool or some other means instead of taking a photo of your screen.

Comment: Why not just click the "new" button and add your path as a new entry?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to add Java to the `PATH`, so you don't need to specify its location each time to execute `java`, `javaw` or `javaws`.

The first one (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`) is added by the Java installer and is the default location to find the binaries there.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the path, you must create a link with JDK
run this command in CMD

```
mklink /d C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\"
```